# Free Open Source In-browser image editors

Tags: javascript, flash, image, canvas

I'm looking for a in-browser image editing solution to integrate with my project: http://code.google.com/p/django-ray/

I got it working with [Pixlr](http://developer.pixlr.com/) quite easily and the editor is fantastic .. however it's a hosted service, which means I must be connected to Internet for it to work ..

Is there any other solution like Pixlr but that are not hosted service ?

*Updates*

Editors found so far:

- AIE: http://www.ajax-image-editor.com/ (feels clunkier than Gimp..)
- Pixidou: http://github.com/asvinb/pixidou (no working demo found..)

And a good list of editors that are hosted: http://www.lifeclever.com/10-free-web-based-alternatives-to-photoshop/

Comment: Interested in the answer, but I've never seen anything like what you're asking for.

Comment: Can you define "editor" in terms of functionality? Must haves, nice to haves....

Comment: Must: open/crop/resize/rotate/save
Nice: not hosted service/layers composite/text/effects/etc..

Comment: I'm not sure if you can make use of its API, but it's cool nonetheless: http://aviary.com/home.

Comment: https://github.com/ivictbor/painterro

Answer (score 8):

## Adobe has discontinued the creativeSDK Image Editor UI

This solution appears to no longer be viable.  Sorry :(

[Adobe deprecation announcement](https://creativesdk.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004788463-End-of-Support-for-the-Creative-SDK-Image-Editor-UI-Color-UI-Market-Browser-and-Labs-Components)

## Previous answer:

Aviary (acquired by Adobe) offers a free feature-rich on-page editor called [Feather](http://www.aviary.com/web-documentation).  It is hosted, however, in that you must perform a GET to retrieve the final full-size edited image.  It's features include:

- enhance (new): Autocorrect your photo with one of four basic enhancements.
- effects (new): Choose from a variety of effects and filters for your photo.
- stickers: Choose from a variety of stickers you can resize and place on your photo.
- orientation (new): Rotate and flip your photo in one tool.
- resize: Resize the image using width and height number fields.
- crop: Crop a portion of your photo. Add presets via API. Fixed-pixel cropPresets perform a resize when applied (new).
- brightness: Adjust the overall image brightness.
- contrast: Adjust the overall image contrast.
- saturation: Adjust the overall image saturation.
- sharpness (new): Blur or sharpen the overall image in one tool.
- draw: Add doodle overlays with a brush.
- text: Add custom, resizable text.
- redeye: Remove redeye from your photo with a brush.
- whiten: Whiten teeth with a brush. (Not supported in IE7-IE8)
- blemish: Remove skin blemishes with a brush.

I'm currently integrating it in a site and there are a few gotchas (they might be my fault.)  I can't ever get it to perform a POST callback to my URL with the finished image URL, so instead I use the objects .onSave handler which provides the same info.  Also, in current chrome/firefox, there is a security exception when Feather modifies canvas data directly from your site.  So instead provide the `url` option (causing Feather to request the image at that URL and then provide it back to the widget on your page.)

Comment: were you able to integrate with a django or python project?

Comment: Yes it was a Django web app.  It's been a while, but as I recall the integration was entirely in Javascript because I couldn't get the POST callback to work.

Comment: Was this before adobe acquired it? It seems to have a lot of licensing mumbo jumbo and they will first review your app before you can use it. A lot of unnecessary steps for integrating a simple photo editor.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't say.  My experience was in 2012 and I wasn't aware that Adobe had acquired them.

Comment: Adobe has discontinued the support for creativeSDK. Unfortunately, this is not an option anymore.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.  I updated the answer.  I'm not sure it was necessary to downvote the answer because it became invalid.

Comment: People looking for alternatives might consult this [github conversation](https://github.com/froala/wysiwyg-editor/issues/2271).

Comment: looks like feather is not available any more either

Answer (score 6):

I've just been looking at JCrop, a JQuery plugin which looks great and works beautifully - on most modern browsers, so check your target platform is supported.

You can see it in action and download the scripts from here

http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html

and you will need the JQuery script framework, available from jquery.com

It's all free and Open Source, so you can customise it as much as you like.

Rob

Comment: jCrop isn't a image editor. It merely lets you crop an image. Which it does nicely, but that's it.

Comment: Also, the last version is dated in 2013.