# Open Source Web Based Image Editor

Tags: web-applications, paint, image-editor

I'm looking for image editor with the same functionality with Paint.

It should have at least basic features like:
1. Open image file from PC.
2. Pencil Freehand Draw
3. Draw Oval or Circle
4. Draw Rectangle

This question is related with:
[Free Open Source In-browser image editors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282833/free-open-source-in-browser-image-editors)

But there is no accepted answer yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Ajax-Image Editor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/akoie) is popular. Another one is [Pixastic](http://www.pixastic.com/lib/), which is JavaScript based. Then you have [Canvas Paint](http://canvaspaint.org/) as well.

Edit: Corrected the Pixastic link. Thanks @Kirby!

Comment: Thanks Sujith! I think I'm going to use Pixastic. Ajax-Image Editor has a some requirent that hard for me to do, like to install imageMagick. About Canvas Paint, it's cool. It has all basic features that I mentioned above except no 1.

Comment: Great! If it served your purpose, you can accept the answer.

Comment: pixastic seems to have disappeared

Comment: The Pixastic domain seems to have been taken over by a Maltese casino company.

Answer (score 2):

[Pixastic](http://www.pixastic.com/lib/)

just correcting the link to pixastic library

### Updated (15-Feb-2016):

The link is not accessible. 
But I found it on [Github](https://github.com/jseidelin/pixastic).